# Why does a Keycloak bearer token appear to be truncated during security filter chain processing

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, bearer-token

I am working with `Keycloak` 16.1.0, `spring boot` 2.6.2 and an external application client that sends a bearer token in to my server application to the endpoint `http://romanmed-host:8888/actuator/health`.

By cranking the debugging level up to maximum, I can see the access token before its processed. I can verify that its accurate by using the `JWT`  Debug site [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io) to verify that the signature is correct.

Yet several lines later in the output log the same bearer token appears to be somewhat truncated, its listed with an error saying that it failed to verify. When checked by using the `JWT` site indicates a signature error, but the token content is correct.

Naturally I would like to know why it appears to be truncated and what I can do about it.

- I can match the output from the client program to the server and its not been changed, so truncation must occur within the server program.
- The program is accepting the request by a get request, since the token can be checked by JWT as valid at this point, its not truncated by the get request input method.
- I have not inserted a filter in the security filter chain, so I can see how any of my code could be doing anything to invalid the token.
- Other than the `Failed to verify token` no other error messages are generated, suggesting that until this point everything is correct.

I can see that the WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, HeaderWriterFilter,KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter and KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter have all been invoked.

I am assuming that the problem is somewhere within the `KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, but I don't understand **why** the token appears to have been truncated at this point.

The received bearer token is

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ3dUhKc1pvWnduelVsU1Zqc2JyTkxsbUNhR0ZIVkV0cTcyQkI5V0pORTVVIn0.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.fwQPLiSIrUSjnRnTBrd1vvGic49OSf7aGDemc0TdmTshZzJ-eYhiEqnAh9-QU2rxDayPIhoIzA9CgBXmGPCnl1Qu4CujDddpBcLpnjszBoBdzwjDgpShgwFpGk0fGCM0fxtSZgMWRfeS_sRjBpRzZ42GelCYZ2E1kZX_E7o_LB3thpiv5oYqgTNucusNmzpm0-iFcEUe5rfnu2ZOHI_hLQvIYKlGURnNld4jov-KDLf2QTh2h3XqjbsGHG9PDq4MbFPhKY_9yF0jQkhF6F3oYrw9MIH4SbemrR-CHw6-aWqGmgucjJ7iKMY5o86HxLPu2tzM06NdaurQZX4ImLCBlQ

Its truncated format is

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ3dUhKc1pvWnduelVsU1Zqc2JyTkxsbUNhR0ZIVkV0cTcyQkI5V0pORTVVIn0.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

The debug log is

```
servletPath:/actuator/health
pathInfo:null
headers:
accept-encoding: gzip
user-agent: ReactorNetty/1.0.13
host: romanmed-host:8888
authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ3dUhKc1pvWnduelVsU1Zqc2JyTkxsbUNhR0ZIVkV0cTcyQkI5V0pORTVVIn0.eyJleHAiOjE2NDY0MDI3NTAsImlhdCI6MTY0NjQwMjQ1MCwianRpIjoiMjIyMjUxZDgtNDYxMy00OGQwLWEwNzAtMjU5YTYyY2NhZDkyIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDg1L2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL0Jvb3RBZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6WyJybS1jb25maWctc2VydmVyIiwiYXBwLXRvZG8iLCJhY2NvdW50Il0sInN1YiI6Ijc4ZTU1YjhiLWQ5MjAtNGQ0Yi1hNWQ5LWIyZDk3MDYzNDgyYiIsInR5cCI6IkJlYXJlciIsImF6cCI6ImFwcC1hZG1pbiIsImFjciI6IjEiLCJhbGxvd2VkLW9yaWdpbnMiOlsiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwMSJdLCJyZWFsbV9hY2Nlc3MiOnsicm9sZXMiOlsib2ZmbGluZV9hY2Nlc3MiLCJ1bWFfYXV0aG9yaXphdGlvbiIsImRlZmF1bHQtcm9sZXMtYm9vdGFkbWluIl19LCJyZXNvdXJjZV9hY2Nlc3MiOnsicm0tY29uZmlnLXNlcnZlciI6eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJhY3R1YXRvciJdfSwiYXBwLWFkbWluIjp7InJvbGVzIjpbImFjdHVhdG9yIl19LCJhcHAtdG9kbyI6eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJhY3R1YXRvciJdfSwiYWNjb3VudCI6eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJtYW5hZ2UtYWNjb3VudCIsIm1hbmFnZS1hY2NvdW50LWxpbmtzIiwidmlldy1wcm9maWxlIl19fSwic2NvcGUiOiJlbWFpbCBwcm9maWxlIiwiY2xpZW50SWQiOiJhcHAtYWRtaW4iLCJjbGllbnRIb3N0IjoiMTI3LjAuMC4xIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJzZXJ2aWNlLWFjY291bnQtYXBwLWFkbWluIiwiY2xpZW50QWRkcmVzcyI6IjEyNy4wLjAuMSJ9.fwQPLiSIrUSjnRnTBrd1vvGic49OSf7aGDemc0TdmTshZzJ-eYhiEqnAh9-QU2rxDayPIhoIzA9CgBXmGPCnl1Qu4CujDddpBcLpnjszBoBdzwjDgpShgwFpGk0fGCM0fxtSZgMWRfeS_sRjBpRzZ42GelCYZ2E1kZX_E7o_LB3thpiv5oYqgTNucusNmzpm0-iFcEUe5rfnu2ZOHI_hLQvIYKlGURnNld4jov-KDLf2QTh2h3XqjbsGHG9PDq4MbFPhKY_9yF0jQkhF6F3oYrw9MIH4SbemrR-CHw6-aWqGmgucjJ7iKMY5o86HxLPu2tzM06NdaurQZX4ImLCBlQ
accept: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json, application/vnd.spring- 
boot.actuator.v1+json, application/json


Security filter chain: [
   WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
   SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
   HeaderWriterFilter
   KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter
   KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter
   LogoutFilter
   RequestCacheAwareFilter
   SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
   KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter
   KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter
   AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
   SessionManagementFilter
   ExceptionTranslationFilter
   FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************
2022-03-04 14:03:30.088 TRACE 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2caa9666, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@67683210, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@58a9e64d, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter@3fecb076, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter@41d84abb, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3e563293, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@25511895, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@21202507, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter@62159fd, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter@28e8dee7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@263f6e96, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@d3b0397, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@75d0cac6, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2267b0bb]] (1/1)
2022-03-04 14:03:30.088 DEBUG 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /actuator/health
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 TRACE 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/14)
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 TRACE 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/14)
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 TRACE 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 TRACE 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 DEBUG 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 TRACE 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (3/14)
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 TRACE 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter (4/14)
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 DEBUG 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://romanmed-host:8888/actuator/health
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 TRACE 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter (5/14)
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 DEBUG 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Attempting Keycloak authentication
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 TRACE 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : --> authenticate()
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 TRACE 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try bearer
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 DEBUG 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Found [1] values in authorization header, selecting the first value for Bearer.
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 DEBUG 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Verifying access_token
2022-03-04 14:03:30.089 TRACE 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    :    access_token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ3dUhKc1pvWnduelVsU1Zqc2JyTkxsbUNhR0ZIVkV0cTcyQkI5V0pORTVVIn0.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.signature
2022-03-04 14:03:30.091 DEBUG 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Failed to verify token
2022-03-04 14:03:30.091 DEBUG 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : Bearer FAILED
2022-03-04 14:03:30.091 DEBUG 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Auth outcome: FAILED
2022-03-04 14:03:30.092 TRACE 99667 --- [.1-8888-exec-10] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Failed to process authentication request

org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakAuthenticationException: Invalid authorization header, see WWW-Authenticate header for detailsr code here
```

The code is taken from an example by Thomas Darimont at [Securing Spring Boot Admin & actuator endpoints with Keycloak](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2019/01/securing-spring-boot-admin-actuator-endpoints-keycloak/) and assumed to be correct.

The code is as follows

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal;
import org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakConfiguration;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.info.InfoEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest; 
import java.security.Principal;

@KeycloakConfiguration
@Slf4j
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KeycloakSpringBootProperties.class)

class KeycloakSecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    super.configure(http);
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(
                    InfoEndpoint.class,
                    HealthEndpoint.class
            )).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
            .hasRole("ACTUATOR")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
    
    ;
}


/**
 * Use {@link KeycloakAuthenticationProvider}
 *
 * @param auth
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
    grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");
    grantedAuthorityMapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(buildSessionRegistry());
}

@Bean
protected SessionRegistry buildSessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}

/**
 * Allows to inject requests scoped wrapper for {@link KeycloakSecurityContext}.
 *
 * Returns the {@link KeycloakSecurityContext} from the Spring
 * {@link ServletRequestAttributes}'s {@link Principal}.
 * <p>
 * The principal must support retrieval of the KeycloakSecurityContext, so at
 * this point, only {@link KeycloakPrincipal} values and
 * {@link KeycloakAuthenticationToken} are supported.
 *
 * @return the current <code>KeycloakSecurityContext</code>
 */
@Bean
@Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public KeycloakSecurityContext provideKeycloakSecurityContext() {
    ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    Principal principal = attributes.getRequest().getUserPrincipal();
    if (principal == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (principal instanceof KeycloakAuthenticationToken) {
        principal = Principal.class.cast(KeycloakAuthenticationToken.class.cast(principal).getPrincipal());
    }

    if (principal instanceof KeycloakPrincipal) {
        return KeycloakPrincipal.class.cast(principal).getKeycloakSecurityContext();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the set up of the client and server programs.

The server used the value

> auth-server-url: http://localhost:8085/auth

in its application.yml file to define the location of the `Keycloak` server, the client used the value

> auth-server-url: http://romanmed-host:8085/auth

to define the location of `Keycloak` where the machine name `romanmed-host` is an alias for `localhost`.  Having changed these values to be the same value, everything works as expected.

The diagnostics  generated by the debugging/trace code are confusing, string described as `truncated header`  seems to be truncated the bearer token, with out the signature.  What the 'Keycloak` diagnostic is attempting to print is the part of the token which defines the tokens permissions and not the signature section.

Running the entire bearer token through the `JWT` site does show that the token is valid, because its a correctly encoded token and is legitimate.

The problem is not the token, but the way the token is being `used`! The client was expecting a legal signed token  generated by them instance of `Keycloak` that it knew about, what it got was a legal signed token generated by `Keycloak` with a different address, which it correctly objected to.

The problem being the nature of the generated error message, it just claimed that the token signature was invalid, had it said something about an invalid/unexpected hostname, the nature of the problem would have been rather more obvious and resolved much faster.  `Keycloak` is design to be flexible, so error messages tend to more vague to cover all situations, hence the message there is something wrong with your bearer token signature which is correct, but vague.

There seems to several schools of thought on how to resolve issues like this, one is to use an raw ip address which will always resolve to the same value. Thus avoid problems like this.  This suffers from if the `Keycloak` server is moved to another machine there are lots of values to change.

My solution is to define an alias value in the hosts/dns server for the address of the `eycloak` server and always use that value in the support files.  Hence if the `Keycloak` server is ever moved to another address, there is only one value to change.